# OpenLiberty readiness probe implementation

Tags: kubernetes, lifecycle, probe

I have an application that runs on OpenLiberty that has liveness and readiness probe. My current implementation for both the probe is a simple empty method that responds “ready" or "up" when called. The empty method is called by a REST service that is configured as k8s probe.

The implementation leverage on the assumption that, after the REST Service is started by the application server, every JNDI resource, datasource ecc... is ready to be looked up and used.

Is my assumption correct? Is there some best practice to implement (for example, readiness probe should check the database connectivity?) There is a way to hook the openliberty lifecycle (for example, AFTER every feature/service is started?)

Thanks